# Going to host a "hidden service", should I "wipe" or edit file metadata?

Tags: tor, forensics

I have made a site that is a hidden service on the Tor network.  I was wondering if there any security risks by leaving metadata untouched for various files including but not limited to stylesheets (CSS), JavaScript, audio files and images. I would prefer if all clients on the website knew as little about me as possible.

Comment: I don't know about others, but images often have GPS coordinates on their metadata if took on a gps-enabled camera or smartphone. Safe option is to erase all metadata for all files, i think that there are even automated software for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is anonymity then yes. But bear in mind that Tor, using a layered encryption scheme through a number of network, is considerably slower than single layer encryption using a direct connection. Transferring large files slows down the network for all users using the same circuit.

Note that each user that connects to your hidden service uses a different circuit meaning that if you have a lot of users connecting at the same time, downloading large media files the impact can be detrimental to a large subset of the network.

Consequently, some nodes may block others in order to improve availability.